# jQuery Recommended way to Style Radio btns & Checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Any plugin suggestions that work well? Please only from personal experience. I can google :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, my plugin suggestion is don't use a plugin - use [labels](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa052206.htm) instead. [jQueryUI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) is a nice way to fancify checkboxes and radios, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This one looks good http://www.openpave.org/~reg/jqueryui-checkbox.html

I've been using this for a while and it is pretty good http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Uniform](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) and loved it. It is fast and very complete and comes with a few very well designed themes (but you can always roll your own if you don't find one you like).

Answer (score 0):

We're using the controls in the jqueryui package. The nice thing about them is that they sit on top of the HTML quite easily so we can just write standard HTML and they work with it.  I'm actually really surprised how easy they are to use and how general they are (button can be applied to almost any control for example).

The controls also have built in ARIA support so it's easy to support screen readers and the like.

Another nice addition is that you can build your own theme on the jqueryui website. You pick the colours, etc and it creates the downloadable package.

Lastly, most of the big name jquery plugins are supporting the standard jqueryui CSS classes which makes dropping them into an existing jqueryui project very simple. They're automatically styled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small script I made for styling checkboxes. Tested in chrome, safari, firefox. It uses jQuery but no other plugins or images. It's very lightweight.

Here's the code
http://jsfiddle.net/mulhoon/8m6xn/